# Delay in receiving updates lightstreamer dotnet client

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, real-time-data, lightstreamer

I use C# and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lightstreamer.DotNetStandard.Client/5.0.0-beta. Receiving updates from the server reaches the client with a delay.
i using this sample code: https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-Quickstart-client-dotnet
console log like this:

### Item update for item1
TradeDate >>>>>>>>>>>>> server: 12:18:49 --- client: 12:18:52.029

### Item update for item1
TradeDate >>>>>>>>>>>>> server: 12:18:53 --- client: 12:18:57.024

### Item update for item1
TradeDate >>>>>>>>>>>>> server: 12:18:59 --- client: 12:19:02.023

### Item update for item1
TradeDate >>>>>>>>>>>>> server: 12:19:02 --- client: 12:19:07.274

### Item update for item1
TradeDate >>>>>>>>>>>>> server: 12:19:08 --- client: 12:19:12.253

Comment: There is any chance to update your client to the latest stable version of the library ([5.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lightstreamer.DotNetStandard.Client/5.0.5))? If the issue persists also with the latest version; could you expand a bit more about the scenario of your application, for example you are targeting a local server or the Lightstreamer demo server?

Comment: @GiuseppeCorti I am using the latest version (5.0.5). I do not have access to the server section. The server is a Lightstreamer server. I want to send an http request when the data is updated

Comment: If you are hitting the Lightstreamer push demo server, please consider that item1 has a very low update rate, so I can assume you are only receiving snapshot images and not real time updates.
You could simply verify that adding in your log the "Snapshot" property of ItemUpdate.

Comment: Another option you should check out is whether your client session undergoes some frequency or bandwidth limit. In this case, with a low rate of updates, the result would be the same as those shown by you.
Bandwidth and frequency constraints can be imposed by the server but also requested by the client. In the specific case of the Quickstart application, a frequency limit can be passed from the command line.

Comment: @GiuseppeCorti Thanks.Bandwidth and frequency were 0.4. I changed the mode to "RAW" and the value changed to unlimited. It now receives updates quickly, but only the first update is 2.5 seconds late. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Switching to RAW mode is not the proper way to overcome bandwidth/frequency limit, you should leverage the RequestedMaxBandwidth and/or RequestedMaxFrequency.
In RAW mode the snapshot is not available and this could be somehow involved in your problem.

Comment: @GiuseppeCorti Can I increase bandwidth and frequency on the client side?
Does not RAW method receive real-time updates? There is a problem if I do not receive the snapshot

Comment: RAW subscriptions receive real-time updates, but don't receive the snapshot, which is not a real-time update but the last update before the subscription.
With normal subscriptions the snapshot is available and the client can request more bandwidth and frequency, but the server may refuse the request. In this case, you should contact the Server administrator.